# Batch File to rename PC using Service Tag with a Hyphen

Tags: batch

I'm trying to make a batch file that can Rename a Dell PC to a name, hyphen, and then service tag.

An example I would like it to look like `PC-ABC123`. The current script has it as `PC123ABC`
The batch I am using seems to work but the hyphen doesn't show up
I tried adding a `-` between `%PC%%comp_name%` so it was `%PC%-%comp_name%` or `"%PC%%-%%comp_name%"` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
setlocal
@echo Setting Name to PC"Service Tag"
Set PC=PC
echo - > %temp%\sn.txt
wmic bios get serialnumber | find /I /V "SerialNumber" > "%temp%\sn.txt"
set /p comp_name=<"%temp%\sn.txt"
echo comp_name=%comp_name%
wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" rename name=%PC%%comp_name%
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
del "%temp%\sn.txt"
endlocal
```

Lastly

```
wmic bios get serialnumber | find /I /V "SerialNumber" > "%temp%\sn.txt"
```

Shows the SN pulled correctly and `echo comp_name=%comp_name%` shows the correct Service tag

```
`wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" rename name=%PC%%comp_name%`
```

Displays `PCABC123` ie "PC" and then the service tag.

```
C:\Windows\system32>wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" rename name=%PC%%comp_name% Executing (\PCABC123\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name="PCABC123")->rename() Method execution successful.

 Out Parameters: instance of __PARAMETERS { ReturnValue = 0; };
```

Comment: Please add a line `echo comp_name=%comp_name%` before the last `wmic...` command and `echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%` after the last `wmic...` command, make sure there is no `echo off` in the script and show in your question the output you get when you run the script. Also show the output you get with the modified commands that include a hyphen.

Comment: There is no `-` in your code.

Comment: A single > will write over the file so the hyphen gets deleted by the "wmic bios get serialnumber | find /I /V "SerialNumber" > "%temp%\sn.txt" "

I haven't used windows in a decade but you could try "wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" rename name=%PC%-%comp_name%
"

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you.

```
setlocal
@echo Setting Name to PC"Service Tag"
wmic bios get serialnumber | find /I /V "SerialNumber" > "%temp%\sn.txt"
set /p sn=<"%temp%\sn.txt"
set comp_name=PC-%sn%
echo comp_name=%comp_name%
wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" rename name=%comp_name%
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
del "%temp%\sn.txt"
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

```all-bat
@echo off 

echo\Computer Name: %ComputerName% 
echo\Setting Name to PC-ServiceTag

for /f ^usebackq^ ^tokens^=^4^ ^delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
    (call^) ^|^| %__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe bios get serialnumber /format:xml ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe VALUE
   `)do 2>&1 %__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe computersystem where name="%ComputerName%" call rename "name=PC-%%~i" | %__AppDir__%findstr.exe =.*;

echo\errorlevel == %errorlevel%
```

**1.** There is no need to create a file, handle reading and deleting, you can directly get and use the ServiceTag in a loop.

**2.** *[`The WMIC tool is deprecated in Windows 10, version 21H1 and the 21H1 General Availability Channel release of Windows Server. This tool is superseded by Windows PowerShell for WMI. Note: This deprecation only applies to the command-line management tool. WMI itself isn't affected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-deprecated-features)*

**3.** In powershell you can try the code below, but remember that you have to run it as administrator.

```all-bat
$NewName='PC-'+(gwmi win32_bios).serialnumber
$PCName=(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
Rename-Computer -ComputerName $PCName -NewName $NewName -Restart
```